# Don't know what's this symbol means

Tags: statistics, notation

I have encountered the symbols below. Can someone tell me what these mean ?
$\chi_\emptyset$ $\chi_B$

Comment: Please provide a more-descriptive title and context for your question. As it stands, those symbols could have many different meanings and without knowing their source, the community can only guess at answers (albeit, perhaps educated guesses).

Answer (score 1):

Since your tag is "statistics" and the following (guess) is widely used in statistics, it probably denotes the function :

$$\chi_A = \begin{cases}1 &x \in A \\ 0 & x \neq A \end{cases}$$

This is called the Indicator Function of set $A$.

Comment: Thanks, I think that's it